# Is there any way to determine why a VirtualBox guest abort happened?

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I'm having some occasional problems with VirtualBox guests aborting.  I'm running on a fairly well provisioned system (64G, 12 Cores, plenty of disk) on a Linux RHEL system.

I've searched but I have been unable to find out how to figure out why this happens or processes that I might use to help.  What do you all determine the cause of a guest abort?

Comment: This question is way too broad, it is not even clear whether you refer to a VBox crash or to a guest crash. In the first case, you find here, https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/VBoxLogging, some suggestions. In the second case, you may find here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebuggingSystemCrash some more info. Pls come back with a more specific question.

Comment: I am referring to a guest crash.  I am simply asking for what files and/or what I should be looking at to debug this.  In my situation, the guest OS gets to a certain point and crashes the guest VM completely and VB marks it as aborted.  So it is unclear if this is a guest problem, a VB problem, or some type of resource limitation that I have encountered.  Later the exact guest VM will work just fine.